# Setting a radio button to checked in jquery not showing it as checked in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

On document ready I'm setting a radio button to checked, I want the user to see the button as highlighted/discolored. But nothing is showing in the view.
Here is my html. Nothing shows it as being checked in the view or HTML. It's the same color as all the other radio buttons.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="SpaceType">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" id="0" autocomplete="off"> House
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" id="1" autocomplete="off"> Apartment
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" id="2" autocomplete="off"> Studio
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" id="3" autocomplete="off"> Other
                    </label>
                </div>
```

Here is my jquery.

```
if ($("#YogaSpaceType").val() != "") {
    var t = $("#YogaSpaceType").val();
    var element = '#SpaceType.' + t;
    //$(element).prop('checked', true);
    $('input:radio[id=SpaceType][id=0]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

I tried both lines including the one that is commented out.
If I add 'checked' to the element like below the HTML shows it as checked but I see nothing in the view as checked, it still looks unchecked.

```
<input type="radio" name="typeoptions" id="0" autocomplete="off" checked> House
```

Comment: check for same attribute with multiple values will end up in 0 elements.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to change this a bit to be more like http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-select-a-radio-button-with-jquery/. The problem here is you are trying to use the input keyword in jquery, but your html is button groups.

From that page, the HTML is:

    `<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">Male</input>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female</input>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Unknown">Unknown</input>`

and then the JS is `$('input:radio[name=sex]')[2].checked = true;`

If it's necessary to leave them as button groups, you'll need to change your JS line to be more like `$("#0").prop('checked', true)`. You could also chain the div ids together like this: $("#SpaceType #0").prop('checked', true);

Comment: just tried it and it still doesn't show. The problem here with this answer is I have 3 radio button groups and they all use the same id's (index 0-n). So if I just set $("#0") it will set all my other radio buttons to checked as well. But this still didn't work for me.

Comment: You can always chain the div ids together like this:
`$("#SpaceType #0").prop('checked', true);`

Comment: there is obviously something that is preventing the button from being checked. I've tried it in another project and I can implement a checked box in jquery just fine. What could be blocking it? How would I check?

Comment: ah! It's the class attribute 'active' that needs to be changed, not the checked value. The active attribute shows which button is selected!!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. I guess I wasn't running the same bootstrap/jquery setup as you, because I was seeing 'checked' cause it to change. Good work solving your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It was a little confusing, but the class attribute 'active' needs to be added to the label. Not the checked attribute. This is a little confusing but understood now.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input[type="radio"][id="0"]').prop('checked', true)
```

Multiple value check for id, will end up in 0 elements.

Comment: space type is my div id, with this it won't know what radio button is selected.

Comment: but from your expression, its not targeting your div... reframe your question.. rather creating kiosk...!!

Comment: could my problem be that I'm trying to set the checked radio button after my validation fails and I go and get my view again for display with error messages in it?